# formatting a url to appear as string in a facebook post

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, string-formatting

I am trying to post a link formatted as a string on facebook. Please see the relevant code below:

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

NSString *modifiedTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<a href= https://www.google.com> My App </a>"];
[params setObject:modifiedTitle forKey:@"message"];
[params setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(picture) forKey:@"picture"];


[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                             parameters:params
                             HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error)
         if (error)
     {
         //showing an alert for failure
         NSLog(@"ERROR in posting image to Facebook");
     }
     else
     {
         //showing an alert for success
         NSLog(@"Result after posting image successfully = %@",result);
     }
     // button.enabled = YES;
 }];
```

The message appeared as:

```
<a href= https://www.google.com> My App </a>
```

instead of

```
My App
```

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, ensure you're posting an immmutable dictionary into the startWithGraph... method by using the copy method:

```
NSDictionary* paramsImmutable = params.copy;
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                         parameters:paramsImmutable
                         HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                  completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                      id result,
                                      NSError *error)
```

That way you won't have any changes to worry about on that object during the method's lifetime.

Next, is your params including any sort of quotes around the url? I.e.

```
NSString *modifiedTitle = @"<a href='https://www.google.com'>My App</a>";
```

That's just a start.

Comment: I made the dictionary immutable, as you did above then I started getting when posting. I just updated the code with the error log, `ERROR in posting image to Facebook`